# Access front end won't open

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have built an access database that is split into a frontend and a backend. This frontend has quite a bit of VBA programming in it. I put them both out on our shared drive at work for all the users to use. However, I'm the only person that can open it. When other users open it the just get Access's home screen where it shows open recent files, new database, etc. However, if I log in with my account on someone else's computer I'm able to open it. Any ideas why users can't open it? I published it as an .accde so all the VBA would be compiled, so it shouldn't be a reference error.

Comment: Just FYI, I find it better to distribute copies of the front end, instead of everyone using it from a shared location.

Comment: Thanks @TomCollins. I give everyon here the option, but they seem to get a bit hung up about how it can work even if it's not on the shared drive. I prefer not to have to explain it over and over ha

Comment: I hear ya. One option may be a batch file they can run that will copy the front end to their own computer. One reason to do this, is that if -anyone- is running the FE from the shared location, you won't be able to edit it until you track down who it is.

Comment: I have now found that when you give everyone a front end, a lot of times when updates are made, people don't use the new version. Now we use a batch and that works very well.

Comment: @TomCollins, I've run into that already. Do you have a link to some good literature about how I could setup a batch? That is something I have absolutely no experience with.

Comment: Haven't checked it thoroughly, but this looks promising: http://www.computerhope.com/batch.htm. Except for about a dozen commands just for batch files, all a batch file is, is a text file with a list of DOS commands. In your case, you want the copy command. So simple, even a caveman can do it. :-) Once you get that working, maybe @JAGAnalyst has an example for checking the version as well.

Comment: @ JAGAnalyst I use a table linked to the back-end and a local one in the front-end to hold system information such as version numbers.  The first form that opens checks that the version is the same in both tables - if they're not the user is informed and the database closes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well I was a bit hasty in posting my question, I just figured out the problem. The backend was stored in a folder on the shared drive that has restricted access so that we didn't have to worry about any user accessing the data, however, that meant that users who didn't have access to that folder, AKA not me, couldn't open the frontend. Solution: lockdown backend and put it on a shared location.

Comment: Glad you solved the issue. Any of those "It works for me but not for you" type of issues can be really maddening :)

Comment: Oh yea, they are the worst. Especially when it's a big launch of a new tool haha

Answer (score 1):

Check that the linked tables in your back-end database, as well as any VBA references to them, have *fully* qualified network drive paths. I have encountered a similar situation related to this issue.

Even if everyone has access to the database as well as to the shared drive, in some network systems such as Novell, each user's shared drive permissions are individually mapped and aliased. As a result, the same network drive path can be mapped to different drive letters for different users.

So for example, when you log in you might see that the file is on G:\Shared Stuff
However, it is entirely possible that another user may have this network drive mapped to H:\Shared Stuff instead. As a result, they will still be able to see your front end database, but any interactions that reference or link to G:\Shared Stuff will fail for them, since the drive you intend to reference is mapped to their H: drive. This can easily happen if you are using the Access wizard to split the database or create linked tables.

If you are using a file system such as Novell that uses drive letters, the solution is to use the full file path, including the part of the path that is being abstracted away by the mapped drive letter. So for instance, instead of G:\Shared Stuff you might need to use something like \\Company Data\My Department's Data\Shared Stuff.

In Novell you can find the full network path by looking in your 'Map Network Drive'.

Not the only reason this could happen, but worth checking! Good luck.